# Random variable from characteristic function

Tags: probability, characteristic-functions

I need to find the random variable knowing its characteristic function. I've found various post related to the problem, but the matter is that I cannot manipulate complex integral, neither I've studied Fourier transforms.

So I ask if there exist an easier way to understand to which r.v. belong this c.f.:

$$\phi(t)=\frac{1}{16}(e^{3it}+1)+\frac{1}{4}(e^{it}+e^{\frac{2}{5}it})+\frac{3}{8}e^{7it}.$$

Thanks for your help.

KB

Answer (score 1):

This is a weighted (with positive weights and sum $1$) sum of functions of the form $t\mapsto  e^{iat}$, where $a$ is a real number. If 
$\varphi_X(t)=\sum_{j=1}^np_je^{ia_jt}$ where $p_j\geqslant 0$ and $\sum_{j=1}^np_j=1$, then $\mathbb P(X=a_j)=p_j$ for each $j\in \{1,\dots,n\}$   (the converse is also true).

Comment: Thansk for your answer. From what you say i can understead that for my r.v. $\mathbb P(X=0)=P(X=3)=\frac{1}{16}$, $\mathbb P(X=1)=P(X=\frac{2}{5})=\frac{1}{4}$ and $\mathbb P(X=7)=\frac{3}{8}$. But how can I know which is the random variable?

Comment: You can only find the distribution of the law, not the value of $X(\omega)$ for each $\omega$.

Comment: Ok, got it. Can you please tell me in which book (or, better, online paper) I can find the proof of the above theorem about weighted sum? Thansk again.